# Which type of data structure use to store this data on iphone

Tags: iphone, data-structures, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have an array of some values that i use in a mathematical formula, and i want to know which is the better data structure(NSArray or NSDictionary or ...) to use? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: can you define better? I mean both data structures can be used.

Comment: ok and which of them is better?

Comment: i mean performance/easier to implement when i have a lot of this kind of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason for not using NS(Mutable)Dictionary (NSNumber/NSString) as key / value?

You can try some thing like this:

`XYPair:NSObject<NSCoding,NSCopying>
{

    NSNumber *xValue;

    NSNumber *yValue;

}`

let the initializer be some thing like,
`-(id) initWithXValue:(NSNumber*)x YValue:(NSNumber)y;`

Usage:
`XYPair *someEntry = [XYPair alloc] initWithXValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000] YValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0.25]];

NSMutableDictionary *ds = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:someEntry,@"1",nil];`

**Dont forget to implement NSCoding (requried for archiving),NSCopying(in order to qualify to be a valid key) for XYPair**

Comment: That seems good but there are really three things to store, so like two keys? Two keys for each value?

Comment: which are the keys and the values?

Comment: @KKK4SO : Thanks that seems to be a good idea, but i have 10 tables like this each of them has 10x10 entries, so it cost a lot of allocation using your solution, for each entry i need a couple (alloc/release)!!

Comment: @funnyCoder: if you are looking for memory, dont bother much about it as much memory intense applications can run real quick on iPhone. It is worth to spend extra bit(bytes) of memory and follow their guidelines rather than reinventing things. Having said that, even I am keen to see an elegant implementation that is Quick (search in constant time, as done by NSDictionary) , memory effective (less than the current implementation) and archivable.

Comment: @funnyCoder waiting for your response , also update if the suggestion helps ?